# Buscar conteudo dentro de arquivo

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de criar um arquivo php e fazer ele varrer um diretorio e procurar por arquivos .txt

Varrer por exemplo todos os arquivos .txt da pasta /files/ (e todos os subdiretorios dele)

Cada arquivo que ele varrer eu preciso que ele tente encontrar dentro do conteudo do arquivo, uma palavra chave, como por exemplo, "MARIA".

No final que ele vasculhar todos os arquivos, mostrar algo assim:

002023.txt - Maria encontrado - Linha 1
002023.txt - Maria encontrado - Linha 10
565454.txt - Maria encontrado - Linha 400
231332.txt - Maria encontrado - Linha 100

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `foreach` usando o [glob()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) procurando por todos os `.txt` em uma determinada pasta, e dentro deste `foreach` utilizar o [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) para vascular cada arquivo `.txt` para achar as ocorrencias de palavras.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach (glob("SEU DIRETORIO/*.txt") as $arquivo) {
    $palavra = 'palavra procurada';
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $conteudo = file_get_contents($arquivo);
    $parte = explode("\n", $conteudo);
    $base = preg_quote($palavra, '/');
    $base = "/^.*$base.*\$/m";
    if(preg_match_all($base, $parte[0], $achado)){
        echo "achou:\n";
        echo implode("\n", $achado[0]);
    }else{
        echo "não achou";
    }
}
```

Acho que isso é o suficiente pra te ajudar.

Comment: Implementando a resposta do Daniel:
Pode-se utilizar um comando linux (caso você estiver trabalhando em um server linux), buscando os arquivos que você quer antes de trabalhar internamente com eles.

Faça testes com o "exec":
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php

e utilize o comando find do linux:
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Busca-por-string-dentro-dos-arquivos

Boa sorte!